# How can I submit a <li> with a form inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using an `AJAX` response from a `database` to generate an accordion list of products. 
The response is parsed and a set of list items similar to the one below is assigned to a var called 'products' and appended to a div inside of the accordions  tag using `$("#my_div").append(products)`. 
Everything works flawlessly within my form with the important exception that submits seems to submit, but the `AJAX` never triggers. Any ideas?

```js
$('.form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sku = $("#sku").val();
    var product = $("#prod_01").val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajaxurl,
    nonce: nonce,
    data: {
        action: 'doSomething',
        sku: sku,
        product: product,
        }
     }).done(function(response) {
        // process my response 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="accordion-item">
   <h3 class="accordion-thumb">Option1</h3>
   <div id="id_01" class="item">
      <form id="Form_01" class="form" method="post">
        <h3>Blue Car</h3>
        <input id="sku" name="sku" type="hidden" value="1001">
        <input id="prod_01" name="prod_01" type="hidden" value="blue car">
        </div>
        <button id="Btn_01" type="submit" class="">Select This product</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check my snippet, it seems to work just fine. I'm sending the request to a dummy page which just returns my requested parameters. Your htlm structure included a closing div tag which was in the wrong place. I cant help you with nonce, maybe the flaw is there.

```js
$('.form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sku = $("#sku").val();
    var product = $("#prod_01").val();
    console.log(sku);
    console.log(product);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://httpbin.org/post',
    data: {
        action: 'doSomething',
        sku: sku,
        product: product,
        }
     }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="accordion-item">
   <h3 class="accordion-thumb">Option1</h3>
   <div id="id_01" class="item">
      <form id="Form_01" class="form" method="post">
        <h3>Blue Car</h3>
        <input id="sku" name="sku" type="hidden" value="1001">
        <input id="prod_01" name="prod_01" type="hidden" value="blue car">
        <button id="Btn_01" type="submit" class="">Select This product</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: That div issue was simply the copy I made. I just rechecked the tags to ensure none were in the wrong place and they were good. I also noticed that on my code I oringially console.log'd the vars before the AJAX call and nothing ever made it through. I even added a generic console.log('debug point'); to see if the form submit was even being triggered and it was not. It seems that the source of the problem is that the submit button triggers a submit, the form method is post, but the $('.form').on('submit', function(e) is not listening.

Comment: But check my answer, it is working @simlpymarkb you prevent EVERY form from submitting. Did u copy paste my code to your page?

Comment: Checking it now. Thanks.

Comment: when I render your code on the JS side and then use $("#my-div").append(my-accordian-li-code); it fails. if I add your code directly to the PHP it works.

Comment: @simlpymarkb run the snippet on SO. you should work your way from there. I cant tell whats the problem with your code if you dont post it. Edit your question and I'll gladly help you :)

Comment: Aaron- it's an internal form from a multidimensional arrray. The AJAX that creates  the accordian works great. each <li> contains it's own form with a set of options, this is then .append to to the HTML which works fine. but- the <li> Submit/AJAX fails and problem is with me sending th <li> back to the DOM using .append. If I add the <li> code directly to my original .PHP, the second AJAX works fine. I will have to use that as my starting point for troubleshooting this. :-/ thank you all for the help though. At least I have some idea of why it is tanking. I just need to figure out a fix now.

Answer (score 0):

For the curious! I resolved the issue. It had to do with the way it was all being rendered in the DOM. I ended up modifying my form submit to compensate. I changed it from `$('.form').on('submit', function(e)` to `$(document).on('submit', '.form', function(e)` and that resolved the issue.